Nested Inline RTE references in AEM GraphQL
Im working with AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) content fragments and trying to fetch the data using Graph QL.
Below is my query -
{
  productByPath(_path: "/content/dam/my/product", variation:"master") {
    item {
      productDescription {
        html
      }
    }
    _references {
      ... on DisclaimerModel {
        productDisclaimer {
          html
        }
      }
      ... on DiscountModel {
        _path
        discountPercent
      }
      ... on AbnModel {
        _path
        abn
      }
    }
  }
}

I am trying to fetch all content fragment references from the productDescription RTE (Rich Text Editor) of the product content fragment. The query works fine and I am able to fetch the references.
Now the productDisclaimer is also an RTE and also contains references to other content fragments that I want to fetch. If there a way to nest _references ? I tried but it doesn't work. Please help!
